# How can I stop Google Search Console "index coverage" emails for the HTTP site now that I have migrated to HTTPS?

Tags: google-search-console, https, http, notification

We have migrated our site to HTTPS from HTTP, so added HTTPS site in Google search console. But didn't remove HTTP site.

We are receiving notifications continuously for HTTP site for index coverage issues. Is it possible that can we stop this notification without removing the site from search console?

Answer (score 1):

You should do 301 (Moved Permanently) redirect for the request received with http to https.

The “301” status code is one of many HTTP responses, that tell us and search engines what is happening with that URL. “301” means this URL has moved permanently and as such, should only be used for permanent redirection, meaning any links featuring the URL that the 301 moved permanently response is received for, should be redirected to the new URL provided.

[Read more](https://www.hallaminternet.com/301-redirects-what-why-how/) about 301 redirect.

If you have already done 301 redirect, for other problems please check this [blog](https://www.blogsaays.com/fix-index-coverage-issues-google-search-console/).

Answer (score 0):

Google is in the process of making improvements in this area.  Soon you won't have to add HTTP, HTTPS, and different sub-domains separately.  [Google announced](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/01/focusing-on-new-search-console.html) that it is working on being able to add a domain:

> ... users need a more comprehensive view of their website and so we will soon add the option of managing a search console account over an entire domain (regardless of schema type and sub-domains).

It isn't clear exactly when that will happen.  Google is retiring the "property sets" feature in April and I'm hoping we can start adding domains around the same time that property sets go away.

Until then, you either need to ignore the emails, or remove the HTTP property.   If you are sure everything is migrated to HTTPS properly, there shouldn't be much value in having the HTTP property around anymore.  It certainly won't hurt your site in any way to remove the property.   You just won't have access to historical data or be able to use it to look for additional problems.

Answer (score 0):

First check HTTP Status of your website, you can check with any online HTTP status checker, the redirect should be **301 (permanent)** and the Http status should be **200** of all pages, if you'r website's both http status are correct than the notification from google console will automatically get resolved, after few days.